# Показ ProgressBar во время длительной загрузки формы

Tags: wpf, c#

Здравствуйте!

Есть следующая задача. Есть основная форма WPF, содержащая кнопку для запуска другой формы. В силу определенных обстоятельств вторая форма загружается долго, при этом первая становится недоступной, т.е. тупо зависает, поэтому в данном случае мне хотелось бы применить, если это возможно, control ProgressBar. Как сделать так, чтобы ProgressBar показывал процесс загрузки, пока вторая форма загружается, а после ее отображения я просто скрывал бы первую форму вместе с ProgressBar.

Comment: А как Вы собираетесь вычислять процент готовности второй формы? Я так понимаю, в Вашем случае основная задержка происходит в момент выполнения системного, а не Вашего кода. Соответственно, либо надо брать ту задачу, которая требует много времени, в свои руки и обновлять прогрессбар, либо увы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для того, чтобы это сделать есть два способа. Первый заключается в запуске отдельного потока, который будет выполнять работу по загрузке и обновлять прогрессбар.

Второй способ, старый метод, заключается в том, что можно во время загрузки обновлять прогрессбар и вызывать обработку событий.

Comment: Ну, разумеется, я имел в виду случай, когда тормозит загрузка данных формы, а не само её создание..